# What datatype is a datediff in Postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have a postgres sql DB i want to insert date difference variable in a table I am doing

```
INSERT INTO new_table (timediff)
values ('0 days 00:00:00.000000000')
```

It throws an error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type abstime: "0 days 00:00:00.000000000"
```

what data type is this and how to insert the row in the table

Comment: It is an interval data type.  I think this is pretty well explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has full support for [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) data types.  This works:

```
create table new_table (timediff interval);

insert into new_table (timediff)
    values ('0 days 00:00:00.000000000'::interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the data type `abstime`, which is an obsolete timestamp type that was removed in PostgreSQL v12.

Apart from the fact that you shouldn't use that data type at all, it seems that you want to store time intervals, so use `interval`.